# Javascript Library with typings is Not a Module (React Native)

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, es6-modules

I'm trying to integrate a Javascript Library (Microsoft Playfab) into my React Native app as per recommended [here](https://community.playfab.com/questions/17622/do-you-have-a-sdkwrapper-for-react-native.html). The library comes with typings and has the structure as shown [here](https://github.com/PlayFab/JavaScriptSDK/tree/master/PlayFabSdk). I have a file `playfabWrapper.ts` with the following.

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/playfab-web-sdk/src/Typings/PlayFab/PlayfabClientApi.d.ts" />

import Playfab from 'playfab-web-sdk/src/PlayFab/PlayFabClientApi.js';

function test(titleId: string, customId: string/*, success: (data: PlayFabClientModels.LoginResult) => void, error: (message: string) => void*/): void {
    Playfab.ClientApi.LoginWithCustomID({
        TitleId: titleId,
        CustomId: customId,
        CreateAccount: true,
    }, (result: any, problem: any) => {
        ...
    });
}
```

This gives me the error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'playfab-web-sdk/src/PlayFab/PlayFabClientApi.js'. '/Users/../project/node_modules/playfab-web-sdk/src/PlayFab/PlayFabClientApi.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/playfab-web-sdk` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'playfab-web-sdk/src/PlayFab/PlayFabClientApi.js';`
```

Then I tried copying the typings from Typings/Playfab and pasting them in the same location as `PlayFabClientApi.js`. This gives me the following error.

```
File '/Users/../project/node_modules/playfab-web-sdk/src/PlayFab/PlayFabClientApi.d.ts' is not a module.
```

Interestingly, if I delete the import line my IDE can detect `Playfab` correctly but it is always undefined. Am I missing something? Is this kind of library even possible to import? I notice it doesn't have an `index.d.ts`, could that contribute to the issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For now, I am just using the Playfab REST API. I will update here if I make any further progress on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it doesn't have any type info (the `index.d.ts` file), you can't import it that way.  You can try`var PlayFab = require("...")` (but that depends on your context).

Comment: I tried that and got an `undefined is not an object` error. I'm just trying to use the functions from `PlayFabClientApi.js`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PlayFab but if you look at the bottom of [PlayFabClientApi.js](https://github.com/PlayFab/JavaScriptSDK/blob/master/PlayFabSdk/src/PlayFab/PlayFabClientApi.js), it's not exporting anything (which would be needed to use it via an import).  Instead, it seems to be installing itself on the Phaser object, but silently does nothing if there's no Phaser object.  Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Hm okay. I know Phaser is an HTML5 game framework so that is probably the optional support for that. I will keep looking, I appreciate the help. :)